# How to track down Uglify error with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, uglifyjs

When I build my Ember CLI app in development, it works fine. When I try to build it for production, Uglify gets upset:

```
$ ember build --environment=production
version: 1.13.15
Build failed.
File: assets/vendor.js (70503:3)
Unexpected token name «use», expected punc «,»
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1508:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1516:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2008:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2016:9)
    at expect_token (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2029:9)
    at expect (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2032:36)
    at expr_list (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2535:44)
    at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2674:30)
    at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2651:20)
    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michael/Code/queue/node_modules/broccoli-uglify-sourcemap/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2527:20)
```

I'm at a loss for what this error means - `Unexpected token name «use», expected punc «,»` - and `assets/vendor.js (70503:3)` isn't a file I can find anywhere.

If anybody can give me a suggestion of how to track down this error, I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on this topic, as I too suffered from "something similar".

In my ember project, I use `ember-browserify` which does the job of copying NPM scripts into `vendor.js`

It turns out that `ember-browserify` does not convert ES5/ES6 scripts when doing this copying, and `uglify-js` (the addon crashing) does not support the ES syntax.

You can see this issue: https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify/issues/97 and https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448

Here is how I resolved the issue (surprisingly easy)

*On the terminal:* `npm install --save-dev ember-browserify babelify babel-preset-es2015`

*environment.js*

```html
browserify: {
  extensions: ['.js'],
  transform: [
    ['babelify', { presets: ["es2015"]}]
  ]
},
```

Now, when you run `ember build --environment=production` it will not throw the syntax error.

---

By the way, a helpful way that I zero'd in on this strange issue is to install uglifyjs globally on command line and ran it manually until I found a reasonable line number to discover the issue with (let vs var).

---

Keep in mind that ember build will only run on things actually installed in node_modules. While debugging this issue, one gotcha was having different installed versions while doing some trial/error testing.

Answer (score 1):

Running `ember init` and replacing `bower.json` and `package.json` made the error go away.